# CakePHP 1.3 : View helper "DateFormat" not displayed

Tags: php, cakephp, view-helpers

I want to display 3 simple selectboxes for "year","month","day" in cakePHP 1.3.

```
<?php echo $form->input(
        'trial_start',
        array(
            'div'=>null,
            'dateFormat' =>'YMD',
            'minYear' =>date('Y'),
            'maxYear' => date('Y')+5,
            'monthNames' => false,
            'empty'=>true,
            'label'=>false          ));  ?>
    ～
    <?php echo $form->input(
        'trial_end',
        array(
            'div'=>null,
            'dateFormat' =>'YMD',
            'minYear' =>date('Y'),
            'maxYear' => date('Y')+5,
            'monthNames' => false,
            'empty'=>true,
            'label'=>false          ));  ?>
```

In local environment, boxes are perfectly displayed but in my production server (same PHP and cakePHP version), the "trial_start" is not generated (see below images)

In my local server:

[image]

In my production server:

[image]

The 2 projects contain the same files and access to the same DB.

I would really appreciate any help .
Thank you

Comment: Still make sure column type is same for trial_start in both db.

Comment: Thank you. As I've mentioned, both projects are using the same DB.

Comment: yeah I know still nothing else can possible here. Make sure you have clear all cache in /app/models/cache & others to reflect your db changes.

Comment: oh! It works ~ You save me many hours of research ~  Thank you for your help !

Comment: yeah sure done, so it might help others in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented it seems to be cache issue. If you have made recently any changes to your db just try clearing your cache from folder `/app/tmp/`.

Another trick to clear cache is,

- First change the debug level to 3 in your core.php file.
- Reload your application in browser.
- Change the debug level back to 0.

**Remember:** Any time you add a new model or adjust your associations or make changes in structure of your database table, be sure to delete the cache folder from the `/app/tmp/` folder.